# Can't access variable outside of function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

```
//get user email
    let userEmail = '';
    User.findOne({ _id: userId })
        .then(user => {
            if (!user) {
                return res.status(401).json({
                    message: "Could not find user in database. Make sure you have an account and try again"
                });
            }
            userEmail = user.email;
            console.log('This is the email01' + userEmail);
        }).catch(error => {
            return res.status(500).json({
                message: "Something went wrong with the server. Please try again."
            });
        });
    console.log('This is the email' + userEmail);
```

For some reason, I can console.log the email when calling in the User.findOne method... however, when I try to access it outside of the function, it no longer exists.  Please help.

Comment: Hi gallowaystorm, JavaScript will not wait for your ```User.findOne...``` it will continue execution and that's why userEmail is empty. Read about https://javascript.info/async how JavaScript is working + https://medium.com/jspoint/javascript-promises-and-async-await-as-fast-as-possible-d7c8c8ff0abc this is nice article about everything

Comment: Async,. Basically findOne happens in the future, the console log happens on the next line..

Answer (score 2):

It's not that you can't access it, it's that it hasn't been set yet. The `User.findOne` call returns a Promise (which is why you can call `.then` on it). When you call `findOne` the code continues on its execution path, which will then call your console.log. However, the logic within the `then` clause may or may not have completed (likely not, since there will be some latency with the database call).